# YouTube subtitle text search?

Tags: youtube, subtitles, text

If I have a list of YouTube video URLs, how do I search text strings in the English subtitles?

The automatically generated subtitles should be used if possible: use human subtitles if they are available.

Comment: what do you mean by "text strings" ??

Comment: @User0 Search subtitles for text.

Comment: so let me put it in other words... you want to search for any given word from subtitles which are part of video uploaded on youtube and all you have is an URL?

Comment: @User0 exactly.

Comment: well thats not possible at all. you would need to download all subtitles and then run a batch script to find what you need

Comment: @user0 How to mass-download subtitles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to mass-download subtitles:**

- download this: **https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl.exe**
- in a folder where you downloaded **youtube-dl.exe** create batch file **BATCH.cmd** with content:

```
youtube-dl.exe -o %%(autonumber)s-%%(title)s.%%(ext)s --all-subs -a feed.txt
```

- in a folder where you downloaded **youtube-dl.exe** create text file **feed.txt** with content like:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsnyl8llfH4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66OpdgDgjBQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB9n2gHsHN4
```

- run/execute **BATCH.cmd** by double-clicking
- wait until cmd window closes (it can take a time - depends on your internet speed)